# Can I recover a deleted Whatsapp conversation in iPhone?

Tags: whatsapp.app

I deleted a Whatsapp conversation around 10 days ago (dragged the conversation > more > delete chat) on my iPhone.

iCloud backup was turned off at the time. I guess I’ve definitely lost it. I wonder if it may have been saved to the Google servers?

Is there any way to recover it?

Any help much welcome.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if it may have been saved to the Google servers?

WhatsApp backup from an iPhone is never saved to Google's servers.

From your problem description, you have apparently lost the conversation forever.